# 34grid - how to remove link and hover

Tags: html, css, 34grid

I just started using [34grid](http://34grid.com/) and can't get rid of the links that are associated with divs. I removed the code that I thought was generating the links:

```
$('.container > .row > div:first-child').click(function() {

    // select current cols and it's complements
    var _doNotSelect = '.' + $(this).attr('class') + ', ' + '.' + $(this).attr('class') + 'c';

    // show / hide rows
    $('.container > .row > div').not(_doNotSelect).toggle();

});
```

but the divs still behave as links when mouse roll over (pointer changes to hand). I may use css to make it pointer but I want to understand why the hand appears.

Would be grateful for help.
Thanks

Comment: The hand appears because the browser still thinks that the `div` is a link. It is possible that the css `hover` is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply SRing. 
I removed all hover states from css as well. So I run out of ideas what is the problem :/

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I missed cursor: pointer; in css. Solved!